# Saving Model in Laravel does not work - SQL Error column has no default value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I'm trying to save a Model to my database. But for some reason it does not work. This is the error I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'token' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `user_registration_tokens` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-03-21 17:40:13, 2022-03-21 17:40:13))
```

But when I dump my model I can see that the values have been set. But I can't find `token` and `user_id` in the sql query inside the error message.

My model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

/**
 * @property string $token;
 *
 * @property int $user_id;
 */
class UserRegistrationToken extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory;

    public string $token;

    public int $user_id;
}
```

How I'm trying to save the model:

```php
$registrationToken = new UserRegistrationToken;

$registrationToken->user_id = $userId;
$registrationToken->token = '$token';

$registrationToken->save();
```

NOTE: When trying to save the item trough mass assignment it works. For security reasons I don't want this.

Comment: Probably not the complete issue but `$registrationToken->token = '$token';` just has to be wrong. The quotes are unnecessary, but using single quotes will pass a string, the string `$token` and nothing else

Comment: `$token` has no value, and it looks like the field is not nullable.

Comment: Models in Laravel do not have local properties for each of their columns. Defining `public string $token`, and `public int $user_id` isn't necessary, and _might_ be causing this issue. When you call `->save()`, it looks like the only things it's trying to persist is the timestamps `created_at` and `updated_at` (automatic if your model has and uses Timestamps). If you comment those properties out, does it work?

Comment: @TimLewis removing the properties works. Thanks! But why is it like that? I mean when I'm looking at a model I want to see which properties the model has. The solution would be to define them in a comment above. I'm just curious. :)

Comment: That's honestly a great question, but I don't have an answer for that. I understand what you're trying to do, and it would be correct for many other ORMs, but it likely has something to do with how Models "magically" map their database columns to properties. You manually setting them like that appears to break that functionality. A comment works, but you can also define them in `protected $casts = ['token' => 'string', 'user_id' => 'integer']`, etc.

Comment: you would have to define them in comments ... Eloquent knows nothing about your schema until it does a query and gets something returned as it is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a  `$fillable` to your model!

Remove `public string $token; and public int $user_id;`

Also you may set `token` and `user_id`  `nullable` in your db structure.

```
protected $fillable=['token','user_id'];
```

Then you may use it in your controller like this(Or like what you’ve done before):

```
UserRegistrationToken::create([

'token'=>$token,
'user_id'=>$userId

]);
```

Comment: This works, just note that `protected $fillable = ['token', 'user_id'];` has no effect on the code in the question, i.e. when you a model is instatiated via the `$registrationToken = new UserRegistrationToken();` method. They already said they had no issue with "mass assignment" (which is the `::create()` method): *"NOTE: When trying to save the item trough mass assignment it works. [...]"*. The only part of your answer that is relevant to the question being asked is *"Remove `public string $token;` and `public int $user_id;`"* 

Comment: Please note that he said “ I mean when I'm looking at a model I want to see which properties the model has“ :). Also I tried to say his way to implement the code in controller is correct too.

Comment: Yup, makes sense   Like I said, your answer works just fine, I just wanted to clarify the difference between the `::create()` approach and `new UserRegistrationToken();` approach. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for providing extra details. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

However fillable need to use for mass assignment as said @lagbox

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

/**
 * @property string $token;
 *
 * @property int $user_id;
*/
class UserRegistrationToken extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory;
    
   protected $fillable = [
        'token',
       'user_id',  
     ];
```

Then :

```
$token  = ['token'=>$token, 'user_id'=>$userId];
UserRegistrationToken::create($token);
```

Comment: its not a "fillable" issue, they are setting actual properties they are defining on the model, not attributes ... also they would have to be using mass assignment for fillable to come into play

Answer (score -3):

Change the annotation to allow null values:

```
/**
 * @property string|null $token;
 *
 * @property int $user_id;
 */
```

And also the property type:

```
public ?string $token;
```

Comment: defining these properties means they are assigning values to these properties and not to 'attributes' (attributes are the fields; not properties)